# Changing background-image url through functions (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, background-image

JavaScript question:

Say, I have an array of links (images):

`var images = [["https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg"]`, `["https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg"]`,
`["https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]`]

and I want to randomly select a new background-image from the links in the array when I click a button:

`function random() {number = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);`
`return number;}`

```
function photoSelect() { return images[random()]; }
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
var urlStr = '"url()"';
var toArr = urlStr.split("");        //so that I could insert the url inside the "url(+here+)"
var toStr, clean;

$('.new').click(function() {
$('.background').css("background-image", function() {
  toArr.splice(5,0,[photoSelect()]); // ig. [",u,r,l,(,"https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg",),"]
  toStr= toArr.toString();           // ig. ",u,r,l,(,"https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg",),"
  clean = change.replace(/[,]/g,""); // ig. "url("https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg")"
  return clean;
});
});
```

I'm new, admittedly, and self-taught and I would appreciate any help or correction.
I imagine there are other, better ways to do this (but I thought i'd try anyway just to see) and I *have* checked related questions prior to posting but so far I haven't found anything that matches mine so I am wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: Back up a minute. `var images = [ ["https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg"], ["https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg"], ["https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]]` is an array, made up of arrays, which is not needed for your data. You'd want: `var images = [ "https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg", "https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg", "https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]` which is an array of strings.

Comment: where are you getting your images from? why is the string of the image wrapped with "[" and "]"?

Comment: now you edited your question so that the functions can not work anymore. why isn´t your images array looking like this: `["https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg", "https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg", "https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]`

Comment: Wow - overcomplicating things!!! `$('.new').on("click",function() {
$('.background').css("background-image", "url("+photoSelect()+")");` assuming an array of strings

Comment: Honestly, that was just some stupid mistake I overlooked Luke, Scott. Thanks for pointing that out. mplungjan, yes I do have that problem (overcomplicating things)

Comment: Also `function photoSelect() {return images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];}`

Comment: It works now, thank you @mplungjan. I can't believe how simple the solution was. I didn't know I could add photoSelect() inside url() without turning it into a string. Now I know. Thank you !

Comment: Feel free to delete this question. The answers are really poor :/

Comment: What is going on here. The solution seems to be quite simple but people are getting down voted without any explanation. Am I missing something about the question?

Comment: ALL downvotes are explained. All answers are horrible and some not even working

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is close, but as stated in the comments, you are slight overthinking this. You do not need any array of arrays to store the images, and there's no need to splice string together when the appended value is static. Additionally when randomly selecting numbers, its best to use the length of the `imageList` rather than a hard coded value, in case you change this later. Take a look at this shortened example

```js
var imageList = ['http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?1', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?2', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?3'];

function randomPhotoSelect() {
  var ranNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageList.length); 
  return imageList[ranNumber];
}

$('.newBtn').click(function(){
  $('.randomImg').css("background-image", "url('" + randomPhotoSelect() + "')");
});
```

```css
.randomImg{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomImg"></div>
<button class="newBtn">New Image</button>
```

Comment: Great. Take my comments and make an answer out of it instead of letting OP delete this poor question

Comment: Tbf, i didn't see the latter comments you made before posing, and with the url appending, it seems like a common thought process. However in hindsight i do see your point. If you strong believe it adds nothing, i'm certainly willing to delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
var images = [ 
                ["https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg"], 
                ["https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg"], 
                ["https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]
];
```

is an array, made up of arrays, which is not needed for your data. You'd want:

```
var images = [ 
                 "https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg", 
                 "https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg", 
                 "https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"
];
```

which is an array of strings.

Next, your code to get the random number, pick an element from the array and use that to set the image can be combined into a simple function.

So, to get a random image and use it as a background on an element, all you'd need is:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("theElement");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", photoSelect);

var images = [ 
                     "http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/abc_2013_logo.png", 
                     "http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/CBS-Eye-logo-880x660.png", 
                     "https://www.famouslogos.net/images/nbc-logo.jpg"
];


function photoSelect() { 
  el.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)] + ")";
  console.clear();
  console.log(el.style.backgroundImage);
}
```

```css
#theElement {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:gray;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<button>Click for random image</button>
<div id="theElement"></div>
```

Comment: `var el = document.getElementById("theElement");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", photoSelect);` and bla bla bla instead of `$('.new').on("click",function() { $('.background').css("background-image", "url("+photoSelect()+")");`

Comment: @mplungjan I think you confuse keystrokes with quality. The OP is clearly confused. This code may have a few more keystrokes (and actually it's less complex due to the removal of unnecessary functions), but it is simple and easy to understand. Just because the OP tags JQuery doesn't mean the JQuery is always the best way.

Comment: I think you confuse overexplaining with confusing - OP just managed to learn the simple jQuery syntax and then you mix DOM and event listeners into this simple thing! My code is based on OPs code. Yours is a complete rewrite using completely different methods

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, well, we disagree. Nothing to see here then for you. Move along.

Comment: @mplungjan Am I supposed to thank you for that? You didn't vote me down, but for some reason you are berating me. You don't like my answer (nor anyone else's) and you've made your point. Time to move along and bother someone else.

Comment: @mplungjan Really? First it was me that posted the initial comment about the array syntax. Second, I personally believe that new JS devs. use JQuery in situations that they don't necessarily need to. They only do it because they see other people doing it. Showing a non-JQuery way happens to be something that I believe is necessary. Move along.

Comment: As I said, I already voted your comment up. There is even jQuery in the title of the question. I see 0 reason to give an addEventListener version to the already answered thread. But have it your way.

Answer (score -1):

**JS:**

```
var images = [["https://samplelink.com/2014/01.jpg"], ["https://samplelink.com/2014/02.jpg"], ["https://samplelink.com/2014/03.jpg"]]

var photoSelect = function() {

    var _imagesLength = images.length;
  var selectedImage = parseInt(Math.random() * (_imagesLength - 0)) + 0;

  return images[selectedImage];

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.background').css("background-image", "url("+photoSelect()+")");
  $('.new').on("click",function() { 
    $('.background').css("background-image", "url("+photoSelect()+")");

  });
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8xgyh75/1/

Comment: This does not work either here or in your fiddle. What on earth is this? `_imagesLength - 0)) + 0`

Comment: You take range from 0 to length of array for Math.random();

Comment: Your adding and subtracting 0 does nothing whatsoever!!! `Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)` works just fine